# How to display only special parts in a list FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to flutter and I wondered how I can make something like that:

I want loop trough a List of Items and make a Widget for all of them. I do this with a for-block instead of a listView.builder, because so it isn't a list. But I want to display for example every Item which has "valid" as value for worth in a different block as them, which has "invalid" as value.

I thought I could do this like that:

```
Text("Valid"),

for (ValuePair item in items)
  if (item.worth == "valid"){
    return myOwnView(item);
  },

Text("Invalid"),

for (ValuePair item in items)
  if (item.worth == "invalid"){
    return myOwnView(item);
  };
```

What could I do instead of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution (preferable):

I would filter the values in the list first, than pass it to your own builder like that:

```dart
List<YourItemClass> yourUnsortedList = [...];
List<YourItemClass> yourSortedList = [...];
for (var I = 0; I < yourUnsortedList.length; i++) {
  if (yourUnsortedList.worth == 'valid') {
    yourSortedList.add(yourUnsortedList[i])
  }
}
```

next - just build this list.

Second solution (bad one):

Inside your builder place if statement on top, and if you need nothing to be built, return empty container, like that:

```
List<YourItemClass> yourUnsortedList = [...];

Listview.builder(
  itemCount: yourUnsortedList.length;
  itemBuilder: (context, idx) {
    if (yourUnsortedList[idx].worth == 'valid') {
      return YourOwnItem(item);
    } else {
      return Container();
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making two lists of type Widget, one for valid and the other for invalid.
So, we have:

```
List<Widget> validChildren = List.empty(growable=true);
List<Widget> invalidChildren = List.empty(growable=true);
```

then use for loop to add the children:

```
for(Valuepair item in items)
  if(item.worth == "valid")
    validChildren.add(MyOwnView(item));
  else
    invalidChildren.add(MyOwnView(item));
```

you can add these lists as children of a column or a row.
You can give `continue;` in place of `invalidChildren.add()` if you don't want that list.